# Getting AWS Elastic Beanstalk health code programatically via php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance on which I have some crons running. I occasionally have issues

```
Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 4.5 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx (2 minutes ago)
```

I have alarms set to let me know about this, and that part is working correctly. But I want to stop the crons from executing if the environment health status is not "OK" or "Warning". Is there a way to programatically get the health status code (shown in image below, circled in red) from a php script running on the same instance?

[image: AWS Elastic Beanstalk health code]

Answer (score 0):

I would use CloudWatch alarm to trigger sending a notification email in such event.

The first thing to understand is that Elastic Beanstalk to a convenient tool to bootstrap the infrastructure on AWS. Anything you setup with Elastic Beanstalk, either via its cli or console, you can pretty much do the same on the EC2 page.

1. On AWS console, go to EC2
2. Go to Load Balancing/Target Groups
3. Find the right Target Group that is attached to the Load Balancer created by Elastic Beanstalk
4. Check the "Monitoring" tab, you should see "CloudWatch alarms: no alarm configured"
5. Click "Create Alarm" and finish off the rest, you may need to create a topic, set email address, and define the alarm triggering criteria.

Comment: I understand. I already have these alarms set. That is working correctly. I have updated my question to reflect this.  But I would like to know the health status within my cron scripts so as to decide whether to run it or not. Thats why I am looking for an api or url/ endpoint to check the status.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `health` script within your application that beanstalk pings periodically, you should be able to determine if your app is healthy or not within your application. You should not rely on having to programically get the status from Benstalk.

For example, within your `health` script you can set a flag if your application is healthy or not. Such flag can be in the form of a touched file in the filesystem. Or a flag somewhere in a cache if you use one. Ex: Memcache.

Comment: Here is my issue. In the event where "Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 56.5 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx (2 minutes ago)", the ping to the health script might still work I am afraid. But I dont want certain crons to run if so many 5xx are generated. That is why I wanted to get the health code on the dashboard programatically. Does this make sense?